# Subset and manually order the labels on x-axis in ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am plotting distances between and within groups. I am sub-setting the data  and want to maintain the order in the boxplot.

```
ggplot(subset(total, groups %in% c("A-A","C-B", "C-C", "B-B", "D-A", "All")), aes(x=groups, y=distance, fill=groups)) + geom_boxplot()
```

I need the order of the subset to maintain in the plot. I tried setting levels within subset but doesn't work that way. 
Suggestions?

Comment: @PoGibas not really. I am trying to subset and then maintain the ordering of the subset.

Comment: But you can specify wanted order in ggplot2 call, second answer in linked post does that.

Comment: @PoGibas Like how?

Comment: `scale_x_discrete(limits = c("A-A","C-B", "C-C", "B-B", "D-A", "All"))`

Comment: Thanks! Works for me.